# I cannot find where lua-devel installs on

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running Amazon EC2.  I am trying to install lua-devel but I cannot find where it intalls to.

```
sudo yum install lua-devel
```

Returns

> Package lua-devel-5.1.4-4.1.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and
>   latest version

Then

```
cat /usr/lib/liblua.a
```

But returns

```
cat: /usr/lib/liblua.a: No such file or directory
```

Do you know the directory lua-devel installs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm -q --filesbypkg lua-devel`

It'll be in /usr/lib64, since it's a 64-bit package.  You'll want to `yum install lua-devel.i[36]86`, depending on what version of RHEL/CentOS/whatever you're running if you need 32-bit libraries for Lua.

Comment: yes i got it. it was in /usr/lib64

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [`locate`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate%201) comand (in addition of a [`updatedb`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?updatedb%208) call) ?

```
locate liblua.a
>>> list of pathes where liblua.a were found
```

should tell you where it is installed.

Comment: Also worth noting that you may need to update the slocate database.  I.e., `sudo updatedb`.